# how to restart angular $http on error

Tags: angularjs, http

I have this code:

```
handler = this.$http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: this._url,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    data: this._encodeParams(data),
                    cache: false,
                    responseType: 'json'
                }).error(function(data, status){

             if (data === null && status !=200) {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                }).then(function(httpResponse) {
                    return httpResponse.data;
                });
```

return handler;

i need to auto restart my request up to 5 times if server is down.
i was try use do {} while {status!=200}, but code doesnt work.

thank you

Comment: Use the $timeout wrapper? And repeat the query 5 times in a loop with some return option

Comment: Put this code in a function. Call the function from the error handler.

Comment: can you help me with the code? i am backend developer, so my javascript skills not good. I can write frontend js only using examples =(